# Selenium giving problems with NoSuchFrameException

Tags: java, selenium

so I am new to Selenium (REALLY new) and also new to Java and want to log into a page and then navigate to another place

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.Close;

public class FireEyeAlert throws IOException {

      WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        driver.get("nnnnnn");
        driver.findElement(By.name("utf8")).clear();
        System.out.println("Element found");
        driver.findElement(By.name("utf8")).sendKeys("nnnnnnn");
        driver.findElement(By.name("authenticity_token")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("authenticity_token")).sendKeys("1nnnnnnnn");
        System.out.println("Element found");

}
```

I cant quite seem to understand why it cant compile! Its a simple code, literally copied off the web.

Oh here is the portion of the source file code of the website I wish to access.

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="sfWWnPWaNhd1qnOh4tIT8KMs4+VNSv7+aF3VTn+BpxA=" />
```

Also, I am using http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo() to understand the concept

UPDATE:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;


public class FireEyeAlert  {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchFrameException
    {

try{
      WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        driver.get("https://nnnnnn");
        driver.findElement(By.name("utf8")).clear();
        System.out.println("Element found");
        driver.findElement(By.name("utf8")).sendKeys("Jnnnnnn");
        driver.findElement(By.name("authenticity_token")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("authenticity_token")).sendKeys("14nnnnnn!");
        System.out.println("Element found");
}


catch(NoSuchFrameException e)
{
System.out.println(" h");   
}
finally
{
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify it and write the code like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
public class FireEyeAlert  
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("http://nnnnnn");
        // driver.switchTo().frame( driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
        driver.findElement(By.name("utf8")).clear();
        System.out.println("Element found");
        driver.findElement(By.name("utf8")).sendKeys("Jnnnnnn");
        driver.findElement(By.name("authenticity_token")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("authenticity_token")).sendKeys("14nnnnnn!");
        // driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        System.out.println("Element found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can't use the `throws` keyword at the class level.

Which also shows that you don't have any method in your test class.

Your code should looks like that:

```
public class FireEyeAlert {

   public void myTestMethod() throws IOException {

      ...
   }

}
```

Just by curiosity, what tool are you using to compile your sources?

Comment: Oh yes, I have ALSO tried that and then editted like i did above.. Im using eclipse, Ill fix my code, thanks

Comment: Probably also want to annotate the method with @Test

Comment: I'll check that, I am not sure how to use the @test thing yet...also in C++, I usually have a main and if i create any class that is separate from the main, why is the main INSIDE a class?

Comment: @ToxicGlow perhaps start off with basic java tutorials. Create some basic console applications with it and it will fill in the gaps for you. Many of your questions can be solved just by "knowing" the language